# How do install tensor flow gpu?

Tags: centos, tensorflow, installation

I am currently having some problems installing tensor flow with gpu support.

This is the guide i've followed.

- Install NVIDIA CUDA (preinstalled)
- Install NVIDIA cuDNN (preinstalled)
- Install bazel

  ```
  wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.4.3/bazel-0.4.3-installer-linux-x86_64.sh      
  chmod +x bazel-0.4.3-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
  ./bazel-0.4.3-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
  ```
- install tensor flow from source

  git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

  cd tensorflow/

  ./configure

  bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

the last one don't finish.. or it does.. it comes up with an error message

```
a@fe1:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

.
WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See http://bazel.build/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more information. You can turn off this warning via --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.

Server finished RPC without an explicit exit code
```

after this should i be able to do this

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tenso
rflow_pkg
```

according to the guide, but is not possible.

i've previously had tensor flow cpu version running, but since the need of gpu were sincerely pressing i decided to install it... but didn't think it would be this troublesome..

any idea on why it is not possible to build it?

os:centOS 7.1
gpu:nvidea

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems attemping to install Tensorflow from source using Bazel as well.It could be that the current bazel build has problems,since that occured in the past with me.It would help if you provided us with information about your system(OS & GPU),but you're probably better off using pip(or pip3) and doing sudo pip(3) install tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: pip install tensor flow-gpu don't work on mine which why i am doing this in the first place

Comment: Which operating system and python version are you using?

Comment: Are you sure the gpu version is supported on Red Hat derivatives?

Comment: I am using an outside cluster,since it is build for deep learning purposes.. I think everything should be ok..